# Netbeans FTP Auto download latest file from remote

Tags: netbeans, ftp

I am using Netbeans remote ftp for a while now. I have my projects all configured correctly. Usually when i work on something i right click the file download it manually and then edit and save (save auto upload set on config)

This is quite some manual work and I often forget to download latest before editing which results in loss of work.

Is there any option to set netbeans to auto download the file (when i open it to edit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It figures to be very dangerous to auto download the latest files without any personal monitoring.

I am now using version control system git with bitbucket. Its pretty easy to use and has private repositories in the cloud.

I am using a desktop app called sourceTree that is recommended with bitbucket but it appears netbeans has a basic features for git built in. I find it much more userfriendly to use sourceTree though.